# Usage of cal in Postgresql linux

Tags: postgresql

```
$ dropdb cal
$ createdb cal
$ psql cal -f mydatabase.sql
```

What is the reason for using cal in this instance to load the sql file? And what does the dropdb do exactly?

Comment: The documentation on `dropdb` is here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-dropdb.html `cal` is just a database name in the commands. What is the context here?

Comment: just loading an sql file into a database. i was confused since cal apparently also refers to calendar.